# Constructing an Epsilon - N Argument for the following Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How would I construct an epsilon - N argument for proving the limit of the following sequence. First steps or solutions welcome. The function tends to infinity.

$$a_n=\frac{n^4}{n^2+2n+1}$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{n^4}{n^2+2n+1}=\frac{n^4}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{n^2}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^2}\geq \frac{n^2}{2^2} = \frac{n^2}{4}$$

Comment: Although I liked what @DavidMitra commented and deleted better

Comment: No, that was (way) off...

Comment: @DavidMitra actually it was.. Heh. I blindly took your words..!

Comment: I believe so thank you for your input.

Comment: @user123652 You're welcome